# What is the right way to add a field in the middle in django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django.

I was trying to design a model in django. First I did with adding some fields, then I migrated the code. Later I found that I should have some other fields. I added some new fields, let say a CharField. Then while I was doing the migration, its showing error like **you are trying to add a non-nullable field without a default**. *Can anybody tell should I add every time a default value to a new field OR Is there any other way to handle this?*

Comment: Certain fields need a default value with Django. You can either leave that default blank (None), set a blanket default, or write a function that will calculate a default value for each entry. I think which of those things you do depends on the use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to add `null=True` to the field parameter that gives you this error in your model to allow for null values or give it a default value `default=<value>` and then re-run your migration

Comment: Other than this any other way. Like my requirement is null=False and I don't have a default value. Excuse me if I am wrong

Comment: I think its probably counter-intuitive to say you don't want a field to be null but yet you don't have a default value for it (unless you would want an alternative representation like `blank` which is how character based null fields are represented). See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#null for more details

Comment: Don't confuse with my question. Actually, it is very difficult to face this error whenever I add a single field. Each time I should go in code and edit there. So I thought there will be some other methods to tackle this

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. Can you show some code?

Comment: Without going and adding null=True or default every time when you add a new field, Is there any other way to handle this error?

Comment: No, you should add null=True if you want to allow null values. If you don't want null values, you don't have to add anything since django doesn't allow null values by default. 
You have this error because you're trying to violate the rules for that field by not providing a value for that field (which must have a value) when inserting